# autoreleased pool explanation

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my code i am working with audio buffers, when i have a callback function that is being called many times per second. this callback is in a class that handle audio, and not in the main class of the app .

At the start i was getting this warning that is being log many times during callbacks:

```
Object 0x93cd5e0 of class __NSCFNumber autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool()
```

Then i was told to put this line in the callback func :

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
```

then this error disappeared .
But i cant understand how is that possible that i alloc the pool so many times in 1 second- and maybe i have a memory issues.
I saw than that i have to put this at the end :

```
[pool drain];
```

so i have this :

```
OSStatus status;
    status = AudioUnitRender(audioUnit, 
                             ioActionFlags, 
                             inTimeStamp, 
                             inBusNumber, 
                             inNumberFrames, 
                             &bufferList); 


    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  // that line added

    //run on evert sample
    int16_t *q = (int16_t *)(&bufferList)->mBuffers[0].mData;
    for(int i=0; i < inNumberFrames; i++)
    {
    static int stateMachineSelector=1;
    static int sampelsCounter=0;

   // CODE TO HANDLE THE SAMPLES ...
    }
   [pool drain];  // issue here
```

what exactly i did here? 
why is that ?
is that ok from memory aspect ?

thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When starting a Autorelease pool with `[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]` all further objects receiving a autorelease or where created with the convenience allocator (like `NSArray *ary = [NSArray array];`, or `UIView *view = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];` are in that pool.

So:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSArray *ary = [NSArray array];
[pool release]; // this will also release and dealoc the *ary from memory
```

If you have a callback running NOT no the main thread, you **SHOULD** do a new pool. If not, your objects may leek to nirvana. :)

If you process a lot of data with autorelease objects and you'd like to free the memory, then create a pool, process, release the pool.

Comment: yes i think i  do have the callback in another thread, its in another class and running while i am doing other stuff- so i have to creat that pool ? , another thing, whats the different between release it or drain it ?, i have seen that people saying that you have to drain it ?? thanks a lot .

Comment: What do you mean with "drain"? When you have a `@property` variable set to (retain), then you can also "release" the variable by calling `self.yourPropertyVar = nil; //because that will do [yourPropertyVar release]`. BUT NOT `yourPropertyVar=nil;// (without self!), that will occure a mem leak!`

Comment: you can also use the "new" language-level autorelease pool: `@autoreleasepool { .. }` (like the `@synchronized` block)..

Comment: @Jonas Schnelli by drain i mean: [pool drain]; instead of [pool release]; , apple recommend that. anyway, what i have wrote in the first post- is ok ?